# How do I make my python pyplot graph contain all my plotted items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, data-science

> I used pyplot to plot all the countries in the world against their
> covid 19 cases but I don't how to clearly show all of them in one
> graph.

> **Is there a way to do it? or perhaps a better idea I Should implement to get a similar result?**

below is my code for plotting

> ```
> plt.bar(countryNames, cases, color= 'green', label= 'Total Cases')
> plt.bar(countryNames, recovered, color= 'blue', label= "Total Recovered")
> plt.bar(countryNames, deaths, color= 'black', label = 'Total Deaths')
>
> plt.legend()
> plt.show()
> ```

> below is my result

[image]

> I was hoping for something as clear as the below image

[image]

> **I would be really grateful for any ideas, help or suggestions.**

Comment: Putting 100 names in a readable way will be hard. You could create multiple plots, each with about 30 or so countries. If your data is in a pandas dataframe, you can use pandas or seaborn to plot. You can rotate the tick labels to avoid the overlap. You can change the figsize to have more space.

Comment: Use `.barh` and change the figure size.